How can genetically engineered crops and animals impact the environments and us humans

real life examples for impact on animals; including bees, cows, and more.
real life examples for impact on humans; including health (like babies born with disabilites due to dna mutations), world wide hunger, and more.
explain whether the solution would be to stop eating GMO and move to organic or stick to GMOs.
Scientific proof (From a trustable orginization, preferably a credible university) for the above.
Is using GMOs bad for the environment in the long term (provide reasoning and evidence).


Questions are often better if you spend a bit of time already finding answers. What have you looked at? What have you found?

Closing this question since it is too broad.  Please focus on one Earth Science question and then it can be reopened.

What's the difference, other than time, between the selective breeding (and culling) techniques that have been used since the onset of agriculture compared to the much more recent genetic engineering techniques? We humans have been slowly genetically engineering plants and animals for a very long time. The cattle we use for meat and milk are very different from their wild auroch ancestors (which no long exist). The maize (corn), wheat, rice, and other grain products are very different from their wild ancestors.
The list of plants and animals that were genetically engineered using old school techniques goes on and on. Those old school genetic engineering techniques were what enabled agriculture to come into being several thousands of years ago. Without agriculture we humans would not be the dominant species on Earth. Modern genetic engineering techniques simply speed things up.
